# Transaction was overridden by a subsequent set

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running a transaction to update the likeCount of my objects. Each `styleId` parameter is guaranteed to be unique. When I like these objects at a somewhat fast and even pace, I'm getting a `Firebase Database error: The transaction was overridden by a subsequent set`.

```
public class LikeCountTransaction {

    public static final String PATH = "styles/%s/likeInfo";
    private final DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Inject public LikeCountTransaction(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        this.databaseReference = databaseReference;
    }

    public void execute(Long styleId) {
        databaseReference.child(String.format(PATH, styleId)).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                MutableData likeCount = mutableData.child("likeCount");
                Long likeCountValue = likeCount.getValue(Long.class);
                if (likeCountValue != null) {
                    likeCount.setValue(likeCountValue + 1);
                    mutableData.child("likeModified").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                } else {
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }
            }

            @Override public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (committed) {
                    List<String> filterPaths = snapshot.child("filters").getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {
                    });
                    Long likeCount = snapshot.child("likeCount").getValue(Long.class);
                    Long likeModified = snapshot.child("likeModified").getValue(Long.class);
                    Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<>();
                    for (String path : filterPaths) {
                        payload.put(path.concat("/likeCount"), likeCount);
                        payload.put(path.concat("/likeModified"), likeModified);
                    }
                    databaseReference.updateChildren(payload);
                } else {
                    if (databaseError != null)
                        Timber.e(databaseError.toException(), databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Firebase are you using?

Comment: @qbix auth & database: 9.4.0

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error, but not consistently.  Do you get it on every test?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it consistently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experiments with the code you posted, I am fairly certain that the problem is caused by this statement:

```
databaseReference.updateChildren(payload);
```

Although this update does not modify any of the same children modified in `doTransaction()`, it is modifying the same parent location, `databaseReference`. Apparently, the Firebase transaction processing considers an update to *any* child to be a modification of the location, which invalidates the transaction.

To confirm this, comment out the `updateChildren()` statement and run your test.  When I did that, the error did not occur.

Comment: I'm doing multipath updates more specifically on the closest commong parent reference, instead of doing it on the root reference of the database, which has solved the issue